# How to export Thunderbird emails to .eml file to file system folder by rule?

Tags: plugins, rules, thunderbird, eml

We are using Thunderbird on one of our servers as a router for a Python script that automatically files bugs for us in Trac (Email2Trac).  Up until yesterday, this was working fine, but we got a notification from Google (we're using a GMail account) that someone was trying to hack our account, and we should change the password.  No big deal, this happens once or twice a year, we change the password, and carry on.  Except yesterday Google was blocking the password change.  We ended up having to recreate the account after we'd tried reinstalling Thunderbird.

During the reinstall a couple of plug ins were disabled, one of which allowed us to use rules to move incoming emails to a file folder on the C:\ drive (Windows Server 2003 machine).  The version of Thunderbird that's installed is old, 52.9.1, but that's as high as it can go on the OS.  I can't even find the original plug ins online any longer (this was originally set up about six years ago by me, so details are a bit fuzzy).

Fast forward to today, we got the email client working again after switching from IMAP to POP3, and I started working on recreating the rules for our various Trac projects.  Except I can't find a plug in that'll let me create a rule in Message Filters that'll copy an email to a .eml file on the file system.

There are lots of ways to do it manually and via plug in (still have to manually click around), but I need it to run as a rule in Message Filters.  I have found a couple that look like they'd work, except they won't run on this version of Thunderbird.  I've tried plug ins from both the plug in repository, as well as outside of it.  Either they won't install due to the age of the Thunderbird client, or they're blocked.

**So, here's my question, what plugin that'll work on version 52.9.1 is out there that'll let me copy emails to .eml files on the file system by rule?**

**UPDATE**, I've installed Thunderbird on another machine with Win7, so it's the latest version.  I still can't find a plugin that helps.  The closest I've found is BackUpMail, but it won't install because it's too old.

Here's the program flow:

- User files bug in Google form
- Google form sends email via GAS script to GMail account
- Thunderbird client on server copies email to a specific directory based on email Subject line to: C:[directory name] using Message Filter rules ***This is where I need help***
- Scheduled task runs every 5 minutes to run a batch file that calls the Python script (Email2Trac.py), there are several different branches to run depending on where the file's been copied to (C:[directory name]
- Python script (not written by us) does magic
- Bug shows up in Trac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a fair amount of research, and digging through old .xpi files on the server, I discovered the answer and why the original plugin was disabled.

After I uninstalled Thunderbird and pulled down the "latest" version (for Windows Server 2003), it was version 38.xx and the plugin, called [FiltaQuilla](http://www.mesquilla.net/mesquillacom/extensions/filtaquilla/index.html) wouldn't run on it.  I didn't realize I was on a lower version until I checked Help > About and found that there were updates to be installed (2x).  So after updating to the *actual* latest build (52.9.1), then FiltaQuilla was able to be installed.

I still had some problems with it accepting the new password when using IMAP, but when I changed over to POP3 it went right through.  I don't know why this is a problem, but it is.  This changes the way things will happen a little bit, but not enough to cause any real problems.

You have to check the Save Message As File checkbox in the properties, and you'll be able to create rules in Message Filters that'll let you copy files into the file system as I wanted to do.

I've got some of my rules rewritten, and I'll get the rest done shortly and we should be back in business.

This didn't get much traffic, but maybe someone else will find this and it'll be useful.